# How can I refresh with AJAX and JQuery my JSP without reloading the whole page?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a web applicaton with java jsp servlet.

On the right side of my web frontend i have a list with links on the right side. (This is my sidebarright.jsp)
If i push the minus picture a pop window will be open (The popup window is also a jsp page named deletelink.jsp). 
In the popup page i have a list of a links, and i can choose with checkboxes which links i want to delete.

So if i delete a link, in the database its allright, but i have to update with F5 the startside. Only then i will see that i have delete a link.

So i want to update with Ajax and Jquery the linklist(sidebarright.jsp), without refreshing the whole start side.

My ajax and jquery part in my deletelink.jsp page to delete links is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#setdeletefilelink').submit(function(){

        var  id=5; 


          $.ajax({
                 url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/issues?action=uploaddeletelink&wherestatement='+id,              
                 type: 'POST', 
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: $('#setdeletefilelink').serialize(),
                 success: function(data){
                     alert ("success in ajax");
                     alert(data);
                     //sideBarRight.location.reload();
                    //alert("hallo");
                  //If you want to return anything in jsp.
                   },
                  error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                     alert(xhr.status);
                     alert(thrownError);

                     alert("failure");
                     $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                 }  
                 });
    //    close();

    });


});
```

My response from the servlet is this

```
    if (lstrAction.equalsIgnoreCase("uploaddeletelink")){   
        String wherestatement;


            try{
                LinkUploadService linkUploadService= new LinkUploadService();

                    linkUploadService.deleteLink(wherestatement);

                    //Sende anfrage wieder zurück zur JSP
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("text/json");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().println("Hallo ich bin ein Servlet");

                    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson("TEST"));
                }
                else{
                    wherestatement = "";
                }


            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            this.checkAndDoBackgroundAction(request);    
        }
```

After the action in the servlet a don't get the repsone in my success section in the ajax script part. I don't know why ?

and the otherthing is: how i can say to refresh the right side bar jsp.

Comment: You are writting `alert ("success in ajax");` in sucess,does this show?

Comment: No, it don't show an alert window.

Comment: Does it show failure alert?

Comment: I the past, i had an erro and then it shows me failure alert. The error was that nothing was send to servlet. But now it is sending the request to servlet, and now it show nothing of the alert. neither failure or succes

Comment: You could be breaking on the java side but since your catch block doesn't dump the stack, you're not seeing the actual problem.  Even if it doesn't help, it's a good idea to have e.printStackTrace() in there.

Comment: thanks. i have an e.printstacktrace. But i delete this in this post, because i thought the code will be confused

Answer (score 0):

You said the popup is a diffrent file. Is it opend in a iframe then?
The success function isn't called, because the form gets submitted, maybe this would help there:

```
$('#setdeletefilelink').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

a form without a action, is submitting to its self, maybe if you try this:

```
$('#setdeletefilelink').submit(function(e){
    //...Ajax call here
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

otherwise, you have to check in firebug, if there is an error or an ajax reqeust anyways..

As the right side, is on the same page, it should go like this, when you get the success to work:

```
success: function(data){
    //an identifire for the right side would be nice
    $("#ID_ofTheRightSide", parent.document).html(data); //depending on what you getting back...
}
```

Comment: Now it is not an iframe. It is a jsp file that will be open.If i click of one checkbox maybe the link is deleted on the databse, the popopwindow will be close, but on the sidebarright of the startpage nothing happens. So i have to push F5 and then i see the result. But i want the result without pushing F5

Comment: Oh ofc. popup, a new window.. :) didnt used that for a long time! :) and the `sidebarright.jsp`, how is that included?

Comment: not calling `success` and `error`, but still gets the stuff deletet is pretty sure submitting the `form`, before ajax can even call `success`... for the other problem, need more info.

Comment: its included in the index.jsp (so in the start page) and represent the right side bar

Comment: <form name='setdeletefilelink' id='setdeletefilelink'  method='post'>
<input type='submit' >

Comment: I have only one action, that comes from the ajax call